# Delaying while loop in AJAX success function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys i have the following code

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost/twee/chat/getnumcom",
type: 'POST',
data: form_data,
success: function(html) {
            var data = parseInt(html);
                page = 20 * data ;

                while ( counter < page ) {

                       $.get("http://localhost/twee/chat/"+id+"/"+counter,function(data){
                       $('#c').append($(data).find('#c').html());
                       });      
                  counter = counter + 20 ;
               } 
          }
});

alert($('#600').length);
$.scrollTo('#600');
```

This is what it does. Originitally it appends data to my window until #600 is found. Technically i have a function which mathematically calculates where 600 should be. This is fine and the div is loaded nicely.

Howvever i added the alert specifically to check if the div is loaded. A value of 0 means no and a value of 1 means yes. In my firebug console, when the function is fired up, the while loop is still executing but the alert already displays a value of 0. Consequently, the scrolling is not done.

If i fire up the function again immediately after it has been executed, i get a 1 which means the div has been loaded.

Is there a way to delay the scroll function until the while loop has executed? I always thought the code would be executed procedurally and the alert would be displayed after all the data has been loaded.

I guess a timer would be an option but i don't want to use that. I am not really sure how much milliseconds i should set the timer to.

Comment: The code design cries for help... (not just because the int variable is called `html`)

Comment: @gdoron the `html` var is the xhr response text, if OP is outputting an integer value only from that call he can very well `parseInt` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous, put your `scrollTo`/`alert` inside the `success` callback function, after the `while` loop:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/twee/chat/getnumcom",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    success: function (html) {
        var data = parseInt(html);
        page = 20 * data;

        while (counter < page) {
            $.get("http://localhost/twee/chat/" + id + "/" + counter, function (data) {
                $('#c').append($(data).find('#c').html());
                if ($('#600').length)   //if there's a #600 element inside this $.get callback
                    $.scrollTo('#600'); //scrolls to it
            });
            counter = counter + 20;
        }
    }
});
```

Note that numerical IDs are valid only in HTML5, if that's of concern.

Comment: Still 0. I get that the calls are asynchronous and technically it should work fine even if it is not in the success callback

Comment: There is nothing more. That's it. I don't get why it's not working too.

Comment: @DpkgMe my bad, I didn't notice you had multiple Ajax calls with `$.get` inside your ajax callback. Give another try now, if that works I'll make a more suitable version.

Comment: @DpkgMe I removed the alert and made a definitive version. =]

Comment: No this won't work at all. I tried and it goes in an infinite loop and i expected it too. I think the $.scrollTo should be outside the success call. It doesn't really matter

Comment: @DpkgMe How come you have an infinite loop? Is this the expected behavior? I can update the answer to call it only once after finding the appended if that's so.

Comment: This is the scenario. User clicks on a link. The link sends over its id, 600, in this case. The first ajax call /getnumcom tells me where the comment should be in a paginated codeigniter page. Then when all the data has been appended, i should scroll to the #600. What you are proposing will result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Okay, should i break it once it gets the appended div?

Comment: @DpkgMe Consider using my last edit now as I fixed some minor mishaps, no problem. =]